# Uploading Image from AWS Lambda to S3 via API Gateway in Binary format

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

My Lambda is receiving binary data of an image from my user in request body (`event.body`).

I try uploading it to S3 with no error, but when I download, the image is corrupted/ can't be opened.

**I also need to return the URl of the uploaded image to the user.**

Please Help!

```
module.exports.uploadImage = (event, context, callback) => {
  var buf = new Buffer(new Buffer(event.body).toString('base64').replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
  var data = {
    Key: Date.now()+"", 
    Body: buf,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };
  s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
      if (err) { 
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
      } else {
        console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
      }
      callback(null,data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can upload the image to S3 as node Buffer. The SDK does the converting for you.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var buf = Buffer.from(event.body.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),"base64");
  var data = {
    Bucket: "sample-bucket", 
    Key: Date.now()+"", 
    Body: buf,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };
  s3.putObject(data, function(err, data){
      if (err) { 
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
      } else {
        console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
      }
      callback(null,data);
  });
};
```

Comment: side note, using `s3.upload` gives you the URL of the uploaded file, `s3.putObject` does not